# Budget planning with Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, report

I have an Excel worksheet which is regularly populated with daily expenses:

[image]

Then to extract a report on the amount of money spent on each category, I simply use a pivot table like below:

[image]

I am not sure how to integrate the planned budget into this report. Suppose I've got the planned budget stored in a separate table:

[image]

How can I seamlessly integrate this plan into my report so that I can know how much have been spent in each category according to the plan? i.e. What's the best way to get a report like this (all in one table):

[image]

Is it possible to manipulate the pivot table fields to get such report?

Answer (score 1):

use vlookup  to complement the table with the link on category.

- create a new table [sheet] called 'Status' that reference the planned budget (optional but easier)
- create first column with something like cell A1 formula is `=Planned!A1` until A7 [could be bigger])
- create second column with :

  - B1 = Spent
  - B2 through B7 something like cell b2 formula is `=vlookup(A2;PivotSpent!$A$2:$b$7;false)`. Normaly the pivot table should be sorted on category (first column) for a vlookup to work.
- create third column with:

  - C1 = planned
  - c2 through C7 formula like `=Planned!b7`
- column D and E are calculation base on column B

  - D: `=b2/C2` (cell format in %) + conditionnal formating
  - E: `=c2-b2` + and conditionnal formating
- add sum in lower cell

`Planed` and `PivotSpend` are name i give to sheet that contain the table with data (but could be the same and also on same sheet as the one that will containt this new array). I assume taht array inside are located since cell A1 (adapt reference if somewhere else)

You can do it with pivot table to be fully dynamic but certainly need to create a temporary data storage sheet with both source table